# Haskell Add-Operation

Tags: haskell, syntax, functional-programming, addition

In a [Codefights](https://codefights.com/) challenge where you have to add two numbers the user [kaiochao](https://codefights.com/profile/kaiochao) had a super minimalisic answer

```
add = (+)
```

How does it work and has this functionality a own name?

Comment: It's called "pointfree", it's an inherent property of the lambda calculus Haskell is built on.

Comment: The author could have written `add x y = x + y`, which is another way of saying `add = \x y -> (+) x y` (ie, `add` is a function with parameters `x` and `y` which applies the function `(+)` to `x` and `y`). You can [eta-reduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#.CE.B7-conversion) this to elide the two arguments.

Comment: depends on what you mean by "it". the parens around the `+`? the `=` sign? the name without the arguments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an explicit definition:

```
add a b = a + b
```

There is a feature in Haskell that says that we can rewrite `a + b` as `(+) a b`, this is due to the fact that operators are functions in Haskell. So we can rewrite:

```
add a b = (+) a b
```

But then we're doing nothing extra to the arguments of this function, so we can reduce this function by removing the explicit arguments*. Note that this requires an understanding of how function application in Haskell works:

```
add = (+)
```

This is because functions are data in Haskell. This is literally saying that `plus` and the function of addition are the same thing.

In practice, we can see this by substituting:

```
  add 1 2
= (+) 1 2 -- Since add = (+), this can be read literally.
= 1 + 2   -- This is how operators work in Haskell.
= 3       -- Calculation.
```

This is known as pointfree style in Haskell.

---

**As [@Benjamin Hodgson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1523776/benjamin-hodgson) mentioned, this is called [eta-reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#.CE.B7-conversion).*

Answer (score 5):

This “functionality” is just variable assignment. It works the same way as writing

```
three = 3
```

`3` is just a Haskell value, which I can at any point give a new name, refer to it, and get something that's (at least, at runtime) indistinguishable from `3` itself.

The fact that `add` has a somewhat more complicated type, namely a *function type*, changes nothing about the way such variable assignments work. I can certainly define

```
root = sqrt
```

...and then evaluate `root 4` to obtain `2.0` as the result. Or, for any custom function,

```
foo :: Int -> String
foo n = concat $ replicate n (show n)

bar = foo

GHCi> bar 3
"333"
GHCi> bar 7
"7777777"
```

All that is really no different from how I can also write

```py
Python 3.5.2 (default, Sep 14 2017, 22:51:06) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import math

In [2]: root = math.sqrt

In [3]: root(4)
Out[3]: 2.0
```

What's a bit more interesting about `add` is that `+` is an *infix operator* (because it consists of non-letter characters). But Haskell allows using such infix operators pretty much just as liberally as any other variables, including that you can define your own. The only thing that's a bit different are the parsing rules. `+` can not be a standalone syntactic unit but has to be surrounded on each side with with arguments you want to add, or with parentheses. The latter, `(+)`, is really what *the plus operator is* from the compiler's point of view: the binary function, *not* yet applied to any arguments. So, when you want to give this operator a new name, you need to write

```
add = (+)
```

Incidentally, you could also give it a new operator-name, like

```
(⊕) = (+)
```

...that could then be used like `3 ⊕ 4`, just as you can with the standard `+` operator.